# MSI Transform - modify registry value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, orca

I have a setup project in Visual Studio 2010 that needs to be modified in the post-build event to change a registry value. I can create a MSI transform to do that, but when I run it through msitran after the build, it fails because the Registry table entry corresponding to that key has a different Registry field value. I need a way to modify a specific registry key.

Can I create a transform that searches for a specific key? What about creating a new entry that overwrites the registry key?

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to just run a specific SQL UPDATE command rather than using a static transform that I imagine does the update based on the primary key of the record to be modified, which varies from build to build.

There is a VBS tool in the platform SDK, wirunsql.vbs, which you can use to run arbitrary SQL commands. Sounds like you want to do something along the lines of 
Update `Registry` Set `Value`='MyNewValue' Where `Value` = 'MyUndesirableValueThatIsInvariantFromBuildToBuild'

Comment: Cool. I have a working solution (make a new entry that overwrites the result of the other one) but I will look at this if I have a problem.